# Three way toggle to add and remove classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get multiple divs with the class 'box' to switch between three classes: 'box', 'box black', and 'box blue' when I click on them. Something isn't quite working with how I have it set up. Thanks for your help!

```
$('.box').click(function () {
    if ($(this).class == 'box') {
        $(this).addClass('black');
    } else if ($(this).class == 'box black') {
        $(this).removeClass('black');
        $(this).addClass('blue');
    } else if ($(this).class == 'box blue') {
        $(this).removeClass('blue');
    }
});
```

Comment: use `.hasClass()` instead of `.class` to check whether the element has that class or not!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak With the .hasClass() instead of class it almost works... I just gets stuck on the black and doesn't change to blue. jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/spencerlarry/mfgpehzp/) .

Comment: It's because your code will always fire first `if` condition and will addClass black to the clicked `div`!

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mfgpehzp/8/) i've made changes in css too! I hope you needed  this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element always has the class `.box` so it will always trigger the initial condition. Try added a secondary initial class like this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o5d7v9qa/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="box none"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $('.box').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('none')) {
            $(this).removeClass('none');
            $(this).addClass('black');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('black')) {
            $(this).removeClass('black');
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('blue')) {
            $(this).removeClass('blue');
            $(this).addClass('none');
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
   .box {
        border: solid 1px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #fff;
    }

    .black {
        background: #000;
    }
    .blue {
        background: blue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.box').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('box')) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('black')) {
            $(this).removeClass('black').addClass('blue');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('blue')) {
            $(this).removeClass('blue');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('black');
        }
    }
});
```

First you check if the element has class box. If so, you toggle between the second classes (black, blue an no class).